# Elbow graph with categorical variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to get an elbow graph in my analysis, but my dataset has a categorical variable and when i run my code, R says that there are some `NAs introduced by coercion`. I suppose it's categorical column's fault.

I created a small dataset based on my full dataset, with some variables.

```
#         x  y z         q
# 1 ADRIANO 20 2      Room
# 2  S.SIRO 30 3      Room
# 3 ADRIANO 50 4 Apartment
```

```
n <- length(data[, 1])
wss1 <- (n - 1)*sum(apply(data, 2, var))
wss <- numeric(0)
for (i in 2:6) {
  W <- sum(kmeans(data, i)$withinss)
  wss <- c(wss, W)
}
wss <- c(wss1, wss)
plot(2:6, wss, type="l", 
     xlab="Number of groups", 
     ylab="Within groups sum of squares", 
     lwd=2)
```

### data

```
data <- data.frame(x=c("ADRIANO", "S.SIRO", "ADRIANO"), 
                   y=c(20, 30, 50), z=c(2, 3, 4), 
                   q=c("Room", "Room", "Apartment"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the columns need to be numeric to use `kmeans()` (and `var()`, for that matter). You can force them to be so using `model.matrix()`. The "-1" means that you don't need a column of all 1's for an intercept; the "." means you want to include all the variables.

```r
data = model.matrix(~ -1 + ., data.frame(x,y,z,q))
```